# CSS or JS Sticky/Fixed Table Header using Easycal.js - two separated tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the Javascript plugin Easycal to generate a table agenda, that becomes as follows: 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Weekly-Calendar-Plugin-For-jQuery-easycal/

I'm having trouble to set a **fixed/sticky table header** with the weekdays, since this plugin appears to use tables inside a table...

```
<div class="mycal" style="width: 960px; margin: 30px auto; ">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="easycal">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ec-head-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="ec-day-header">Monday, 26 Oct</td>
                            <td class="ec-day-header">Tuesday, 27 Oct</td>
                            <td class="ec-day-header">Wednesday, 28 Oct</td>
                            <td class="ec-day-header">Thursday, 29 Oct</td>
                            <td class="ec-day-header">Friday, 30 Oct</td>
                            <td class="ec-day-header">Saturday, 31 Oct</td>
                            <td class="ec-day-header">Sunday, 01 Nov</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ec-time-grid-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="table-cell ec-time">09:00</div>
                                <div class="table-cell ec-time">09:30</div>
                                ...
                            </td>
                            <td class="ec-slot-col" data-date="26-10-2015">
                                ...
                            </td>
                            <td class="ec-slot-col" data-date="27-10-2015">
                                ...
                                    <div>Lunch</div>
                                </div>
                                ...
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I've tried several methods with CSS/js available on the web but without success, since I was unable to fit any to this scheme...

Can anyone help me achieve something like these JSFiddle: [7UZA4/1385/](http://jsfiddle.net/7UZA4/1385/) or DTcHh/1362/?

Answer (score 0):

So finally done with sticky header with jquery . I just create the table with scroll header. Other function are need to be added by you. Like functuon event [LiveDemoOnMyFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/zL26prq2/) 
This Is the main jQuery Which convert the header to sticky, Function resizefixed is just additional. SO if you use this near future give a update . Happy Coding

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {
    $.fn.fixMe = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          $t_fixed;

        function init() {
          $this.wrap('<table class="easycal" />');
          $t_fixed = $this.clone();
          $t_fixed.find(".ec-time-grid-table > tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
          resizeFixed();
        }

        function resizeFixed() {
          $t_fixed.find(".").each(function(index) {
            $(this).css("width", $this.find(".th_head").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
          });
        }

        function scrollFixed() {
          var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
            tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
            tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find(".th_main").height();
          if (offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom)
            $t_fixed.hide();
          else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
            $t_fixed.show();
        }
        $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
        $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
        init();
      });
    };
  })(jQuery);
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".easycal").fixMe();

});
```

Comment: As you can see, the alignments are not ok. Also the columns size is set dinamically with bootstrap "col-sm-x". The main issue so far is to actually get the table to behave correctly aligned, such as in the examples.

Comment: Yes I knw that's why need to play with css.. col-sm-x it's just a class you can modified the class easily ..

Comment: @fsv check the new update hope this will help you out. Finally done with your sticky header.

Comment: I'm having problems making this work on my actual page, do you have any ideas what must be changed? (I've already changed the JS from class easycal to id tabelaAgenda) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxEbAiULzBQeVnBVRVY0dzg3WW8

Comment: @fsv change the jQuery you will find it on custom.js add a css in easycal.css line 1 .floatingHeader .Its work on my window [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwCgahw2cTJAMS0xc3BWM2tySEU/view?usp=sharing ] . If you not satisfied yet you can try with [ http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/ ]  I'm facing some bug issue. Let me know how its work on your side. And I use CDN because I don't get any js inside and datepicker css. Any question ask me. :) Happy coding

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can see on your file, the style of the table header gets really bad (out of position and size)... I tried to fix this but without success. Also mkoryak's floatThead effect would be perfect, but when I use the js function, nothing happens.

Comment: sounds bad. that file I share with you works for me. I dont use media query to make the header responsive. so maybe thats your job to set the media query for top positioning . But I'm really sorry I don't make it perfect for you :(

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you find out why floatThead function isn't working?

Comment: @fsv actually After that won't try that. :(